# Copy files that are different?

Tags: bash, unix

I have two directories with similar files, (one being a backup), what is a command that allows me to copy over only the files that are different to the backup?

`cp -rf firstDir/* secondDir` is awfully inefficient, since a lot of the files are the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rsync is the best way

```
rsync -va ~/from/ ~/to
```

note the trailing / on 'from' is important!
v is verbose mode - leave it on until it's working, a is archive = copy all the file info.

Or you can just use the -u (update) flag to cp = only copy newer files.

Answer (score 2):

rsync

will keep the directories the same efficiently. Will work of ssh as well..